# Android viewPager adapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter

When I close (`onPause`) my application, and reopen it `onResume`, 
`ViewPager` adapter that extends `FragmentPagerAdapter` overriden method `getItem()` is not invoked. How can I invoke it? 
Here is my viewPager adapter:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String TAG = "MyPagerAdapter";
    private int MAX_COUNT = 100;
    fragment1 myFragment;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

        super(fm);
        Log.d(TAG, "Created adapter for pager");

    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        MAX_COUNT = count;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Log.d(TAG, "getting item at " + position);

        myFragment = new fragment1();

        myFragment.position = position;
        Log.d("Fragment", "Position: " + position);

        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return MAX_COUNT;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your view pager in onStart() method of activity . OnCreate() method calls once activity is created .  Or call it again on OnRestart() method .  See [Activity LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) for further details